# How to Put Empty Literal in Code Snippet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-snippets

I've slightly modified VS's `ctor` snippet. The idea is that if I want parameters or a body, I type them in, otherwise I can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to skip and make it parameterless:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>ctor</Title>
            <Shortcut>ctor</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for constructor</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>classname</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Class name</ToolTip>
                    <Function>ClassName()</Function>
                    <Default>ClassNamePlaceholder</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>parameters</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Parameters</ToolTip>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>body</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Body</ToolTip>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $classname$ ($parameters$)
    {$body$}$end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

It works great, except it has a small nuisance in case I want parameterless:

```
public ProjectTask( )
{ }
```

Notice the extra space character  between the parentheses? I know I'm taking laziness to a whole new level here but is it possible to make that go away?

Comment: I should add that I've tried `<Default></Default>` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried my exact same snippet above in VS 2015 and noticed it no longer has that problem and the generated code ends up like this:

```
public ProjectTask()
{ }
```